# How many fixed points does a function have?

Tags: numerical-methods

> How many fixed points does $$f(x) = \sin\left(\sin\left(\dfrac{x^3}{11} + \dfrac{x^2}{7} + \dfrac{x}{3}\right)\right)
> $$ have in the range $[0,1]$?

How does one come to solve this? I thought about considering a new function:

> $g(x) = x - f(x)$

and searching how many roots does it have, but even there I got stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, thanks for the heads up, I edited.

Comment: Since you have tagged this question with numerical methods, does this mean you are interested in finding the result using a program like newtons method?

Comment: This is a question in a homework in the course "Numerical Analysis". It is better if I solve this mathematically and keeping programs as a last resort.

Comment: Now you have two terms in $x^3$. Do you want to edit it again?

Comment: This is what happens when one studies for over 12 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $f: [0,1] \to [0,1] \ $ has the property that $f$ is increasing and $f(x) < x$ for all positive $x$, then $x = 0$ is the only possible fixed point.

Now look at your function $f = f_1 \circ f_2 \circ f_3$ where each of the functions $f_j$ have this property. Easy for $f_1 = f_2 = \sin$; for $f_3$,

$$f_3(x) = \frac{x^3}{11} + \frac{x^2}{7} + \frac{x}{3} \leq x \left( \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{3} \right)  < x$$

Hence $x = 0$ is the only possible fixed point and indeed it is a fixed point.

Therefore $f$ has only one fixed point on $[0, 1]$.